# Dynatree returns error when faced with more than 2000 items

Tags: javascript, json, dynatree

I use dynatree and everything works fine but if a node has large number of items I get an error. I have read about setting `enableUpdate(false);` function but it also didn't help. Any ideas?

```
var serviceParams = { Type: this._fieldName };

$("#tree").dynatree({       
    autoFocus: false,
    clickFolderMode: 1,     
    initAjax: {
        url: tree._serviceUrl + "/top",
        data: jQuery.serializeJSON(serviceParams),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    },

    onLazyRead: function(node) {        

        //this.enableUpdate(false);    

        var serviceParamsForChildren = 
        { 
            Type: tree._fieldName, 
            parentId: node.data.key, 
            includeDescedants: false 
        };

        node.appendAjax({
            url: tree._serviceUrl + "/Children",
            data: jQuery.serializeJSON(serviceParamsForChildren),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });

        //this.enableUpdate(true);
    },
    onActivate: function(node) {
       tree._selectedNode = node;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h5.5)

*tree.enableUpdate(enable)*

> Turn rendering on or off and return the previous mode. Disabling update may speedup processing, when adding lots of nodes.
>       Don't forget to turn rendering back on, after applying the changes

Comment: @Alexander: Than you should mark oleksii's answer as the right answer for your question, so he can gain the reputation score for it.